# Binary search giving wrong location?

Tags: java

Here's the question:

A string contains several X's followed by several O's. Devise a divide-and-conquer algorithm that finds the number of X's in the string in log<sub>2</sub>(n) steps, where n is the length of the string.

And here's my code:

```
public static int count(String str){
    int min = 0;
    int max = str.length() - 1;
    while(min < max){
        if(str.charAt(min) == 'X')
            min += (max - min) / 2; 
        else
            max = min + (max - min) / 2;
    }
    return min;
}
```

It seems to work most of the time but there are a few cases where it gives unexpected output. For example, when I put give it the string "XXXXOOOO" it should return 4, but it returns 5 instead. Why?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger? Start there.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, I am not sure how to prevent min from increasing past the number of X's in the string.

Comment: You can't do a binary search with only `min` and `max`. you need to calculate a third value (the average) and _then_ decide which endpoint to move.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm for the binary search is wrong.  You can find the canonical binary search algorithm on Wikipedia so I'm not going to give it to you or link to it.

However, you cannot implement a binary search using only two indices `min` and `max`. You must calculate the midpoint, in a separate variable, and then use the results of probing at that (midpoint) location to decide which endpoint to move.

Answer (score 1):

This binary search repeatedly divides the size of the string into roughly half at each iteration. The middle is calculated at each iteration. If the item in the middle index is 'X', then the string to the right of the middle is searched. If the item in the middle index is 'O', then the string to the left of the middle is searched. This continues until there is only one element left in the list.  If this element is 'X', then the one-element list is at the index of the last X, so index+1 is returned.  Otherwise, the last X is one element less.

```
    public static int countX(String xos) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = xos.length() -1;

        int middle = start + (end-start)/2;
        while (start < end) {
            if (xos.charAt(middle) == 'X') {
                start = middle+1;
            } else {
                end = middle-1;
            }
            middle = start + (end-start)/2;
        }
        return xos.charAt(start)=='X'?start+1:start;
    }
```

Test function:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random r = new Random();

    // Generate 25 strings
    for (int tries = 0; tries < 25; tries++ ) {
        // Generate a random length
        int stringLength = r.nextInt(75)+1;
        // Generate a random number of Xs
        int numX = r.nextInt(stringLength+1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(stringLength);

        // add random number of Xs to the string
        for (int i=0; i<numX; i++) {
            sb.append("X");
        }
        // add Os to make up the length
        for (int i=numX; i<stringLength; i++) {
            sb.append("O");
        }
        // Convert StringBuilder to String
        String result = sb.toString();
        // Test function with the random string
        int countBin = countX(result);

        // Print results of test
        System.out.println(result + " (" + numX + " Xs, " + (stringLength-numX) + " Os) : " + countBin  + ", " +
            (countBin==numX?"Correct":"Incorrect"));
    }
```

Sample output:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (14 Xs, 43 Os) : 14, Correct
XXXXXX (6 Xs, 0 Os) : 6, Correct
XXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (3 Xs, 35 Os) : 3, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOOO (60 Xs, 3 Os) : 60, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (19 Xs, 0 Os) : 19, Correct
XXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (4 Xs, 17 Os) : 4, Correct
XO (1 Xs, 1 Os) : 1, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (28 Xs, 23 Os) : 28, Correct
XXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (2 Xs, 32 Os) : 2, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOO (55 Xs, 2 Os) : 55, Correct
XXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (7 Xs, 24 Os) : 7, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXOOOOO (10 Xs, 5 Os) : 10, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (11 Xs, 17 Os) : 11, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOO (11 Xs, 6 Os) : 11, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (30 Xs, 22 Os) : 30, Correct
XOOOOO (1 Xs, 5 Os) : 1, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOO (63 Xs, 12 Os) : 63, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (27 Xs, 32 Os) : 27, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (13 Xs, 18 Os) : 13, Correct
XXXO (3 Xs, 1 Os) : 3, Correct
XXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOO (8 Xs, 13 Os) : 8, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (44 Xs, 28 Os) : 44, Correct
XOOOOOOOO (1 Xs, 8 Os) : 1, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (14 Xs, 16 Os) : 14, Correct
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOO (16 Xs, 6 Os) : 16, Correct
```